# VBA Word Asynchronous Execution

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

I have a form in MS Access that allows users to enter data they collect from the field and that form also has the option to compile all of the information into a formal report. The report contains a cover sheet and a table of contents as well as leaves section header pages for additional documents to be attached when printed out/exported.

There are 2 things that execute before their processes are actually finished:

- One subroutine creates many formatted tables but the tables only get created with the appropriate data, the formatting does not apply right away and as a result, the formatting finally kicks in once the document is done typing and will delete any extra pages. This is affecting the second problem.
- Since the page numbering for each page is not the same, sections are used so that each page can have a unique footer with the page number included in that. A loop is used to run through the document and unlink all headers and footers from the previous ones. It then starts from the beginning of the document and moves from footer to footer and writes the page number. That code is below:

  ```
  While Not Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
   If Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) = (Section_Page + 1) Then
    Selection.TypeText "Page: " & (pgNum + Section_Length)
    pgNum = pgNum + Section_Length
   Else
    Selection.TypeText "Page: " & pgNum
   End If
   pgNum = pgNum + 1
   ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter 'move to the next page's footer
  Wend
  ```

The problem that I am having with this section of code is that the Selection does not always move to the next footer fast enough and as a result footers that belong on the next page sometimes cram onto the same page as another footer and the footer looks something like "Page: 5Page: 6" rather than "Page: 5" on one and "Page: 6" on the next.

Please do not suggest the built in Word page numbering - I shortened the code here, there are anywhere between 3 and 7 sections that need spacing. I think if there was a way to get the code to execute asynchronously that block of code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stop-gap measure would be to insert one (or several) line(s) of

DoEvents

after the change and before ActiveWindow....NextHeaderFooter. That command yields execution to the OS. That may give Word the time it needs to catch up.

Of course, you would do better to avoid using ActiveWindow... altogether and iterate through the sections with a For loop.